# Express handlebars not rendering if statement correctly

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm building a todo list using express handlebars, mongoose, mongodb, google oauth. I'm having trouble with rendering using handlebars. A todo has a mongoose attribute of `done`. If `done` true, then a class of `complete` is applied, which is `text-decoration: line-through`. The problem is that `done` is always rendered as `true`. When I click on the todo, it toggles between `true/false` in mongodb but doesn't show in hbs.

hbs:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>To Do</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="flexContainer">
        <h1 class="title main-font center">Welcome {{name}}</h1>
      </header>

      <form class="center" action="/todos/addTodo" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To Do" name="todoItem" />
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">
          <span>Add Todo</span>
        </button>
      </form>

      <div class="to-do-list flexContainer">
        <ul class="task-list center">
          {{#each todo}}
            <li data-id="{{_id}}">
              // Problem is this block of code here.
              {{done}} // Added this line just to show the done attribute is toggling between true/false. Status renders here correctly.
              {{#if done}} // This if statement doesn't work. All todos are rendered with the complete class.
                <span class="complete">{{todo}}</span>
              {{else}}
                <span class="incomplete">{{todo}}</span>
              {{/if}}
              <span class="fa fa-trash delete-todo"></span>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <h4 class="main-font center">Left to do: {{left}}</h4>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

controller todo.js

```
const Todo = require("../models/todos");

module.exports = {
  getTodos: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const todoItems = await Todo.find({ googleId: req.user.googleId }).lean();
      const itemsLeft = await Todo.countDocuments({
        googleId: req.user.googleId,
        done: false,
      });

      res.render("todos.hbs", {
        todo: todoItems,
        left: itemsLeft,
        name: req.user.firstName,
        //  done: done, <-- I'm not sure if I have to pass in a variable for done. The variable done seems to work in the hbs file anyways.
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },

  addTodo: async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
      await Todo.create({
        todo: req.body.todoItem,
        done: false,
        googleId: req.user.googleId,
      });
      console.log("To do has been added!");
      res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },

  deleteTodo: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Todo.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.body.todoId });
      console.log("Deleted Todo");
      res.json("Deleted Todo");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },

  markComplete: async (req, res) => {
    console.log("markComplete");
    try {
      await Todo.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.body.todoId },
        {
          done: true,
        }
      );
      console.log("complete");
      res.json("Marked Complete");
    } catch {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },

  markIncomplete: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Todo.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.body.todoId },
        {
          done: false,
        }
      );
      console.log("Marked Incomplete");
      res.json("Marked Incomplete");
    } catch {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

main.js:

```
const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-todo");
const todoIncomplete = document.querySelectorAll(".incomplete");
const todoComplete = document.querySelectorAll(".complete");

Array.from(deleteBtn).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", deleteToDo);
});

Array.from(todoIncomplete).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", markComplete);
});

Array.from(todoComplete).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", markIncomplete);
});

async function deleteToDo() {
  const todoId = this.parentNode.dataset.id;
  try {
    const response = await fetch("todos/deleteTodo", {
      method: "delete",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todoId: todoId,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function markComplete() {
  const todoId = this.parentNode.dataset.id;
  console.log(todoId);
  try {
    const response = await fetch("todos/markComplete", {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todoId: todoId,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function markIncomplete() {
  const todoId = this.parentNode.dataset.id;
  try {
    const response = await fetch("todos/markIncomplete", {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todoId: todoId,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const todosController = require("../controllers/todos");
const { ensureAuth, EnsureGuest } = require("../middleware/auth");

router.get("/", ensureAuth, todosController.getTodos);

router.post("/addTodo", todosController.addTodo);

router.put("/markComplete", todosController.markComplete);

router.put("/markIncomplete", todosController.markIncomplete);

router.delete("/deleteToDo", todosController.deleteTodo);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: From your description of the problem it sounds like the value of each `todo.done` is a string instead of a Boolean (ie., `"true"` or `"false"`), although I'm not sure why. It might make sense to confirm _that_ first.

Comment: @76484 You are correct. Such a simple mistake. Not sure how to accept your comment as best answer, but I have posted an answer and hopefully SO gives you credit.

Comment: I am happy that worked for you and pleased that I could help!

Answer (score 1):

According to @76484, it is a string and not boolean. I have fixed it.

Mongoose model schema:

```
const toDoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  todo: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  done: {
    type: Boolean, // previously string here
    required: true,
  },
  googleId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```